# Boilerpipe dependency not found

Tags: maven, boilerpipe

According to https://github.com/Netbreeze-GmbH/boilerpipe the maven dependency for boiler pipe is

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>de.l3s.boilerpipe</groupId>
  <artifactId>boilerpipe-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But this dependency is not available via Maven.
Closest I found is http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.l3s.boilerpipe%22%20AND%20a%3A%22boilerpipe%22 this dependency is version 1.1.0 . How I can add dependency 1.2.2?

Update :

I found the dependency at this location : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.syncthemall/boilerpipe/1.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simply answer here is: You can't cause it does not exist in Maven Central. The location you gave `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.syncthemall/boilerpipe/1.2.2` is not Maven Central. This gives a location on Github repository (source repository) which hasn't deployed yet the version 1.2.2 to Maven Central...

What you might need to do is to clone the GitHub repo and build it locally and install it yourself..or best would be using a repository manager and deploy it locally in your corporate network...

Answer (score 0):

You can build project with `mvn clean install`. That will install the artifact to your local repository. Then you can use it.

If you need it globally best you can do is to deploy the artifact (you build) to a custom maven repository. Or ask maintainers to deploy it to central repository.